# Lockscreen widget android in android 3/4.1?

Tags: android, android-widget, lockscreen, keyguard

i want to add my widget in the lockscreen. According with the documentation i know that i have to do something like

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   ...
   android:widgetCategory="keyguard|home_screen">
</appwidget-provider>
```

And the `android:minSdkVersion` is 17. I don't want create my app only for android 4.2 so is there a way to get around this situation?I mean something that check the android version and if is for example android 3 i can't create the lockscreen widget of course, else i can.I don't  know if is possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set minsdkversion to 8.
it doesn't matter.
the version under 17 will ignore widgetCategory property.